# root CA certificate and intermemdiate CA certificate

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I was given 3 root CA certificate and 3 intermemdiate CA certificate to integrate with one https URL. I am new to using this certificate. Do i need to create PKCS file or anything out of this. Please help.

Comment: You need to install them to your Browser/Device (android/iOS). 
If you need this for Browser(e.g. Firefox) you may need to generate PKCS file with a Password.
refer: https://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_options#listeners_exportingcert

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i need to use this cert in my java code to access their services. So, is it possible to convert this file to pkcs file without private key file.?